# MSB4036 The "FormatLocalizedString" task was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have created one new ASP.net web api project in VS 2022. While building that default project for first time i am getting this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   MSB4036 The "FormatLocalizedString" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64" directory. WebApplication5 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets 69

That error point to Microsoft.TypeScript.targets file in this file path
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets

```
  <!-- At least one SDK must be installed for FormatLocalizedString to exist, and if no SDKs are installed, there's nothing to report -->
  <Target Name="ReportTypeScriptVersion" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="$(LastKnownTypeScriptVersion) != ''">
    <FormatLocalizedString Condition="'$(TypeScriptVersionCheckResult)' == 'NoneSpecified'"
      Culture="$(PreferredUILang)"
      Name="TypeScriptNoVersionWarning"
      Arguments="$(LastKnownTypeScriptVersion)">
      <Output TaskParameter="String" PropertyName="TypeScriptNoVersionWarning" />
    </FormatLocalizedString>

    <FormatLocalizedString Condition="'$(TypeScriptVersionCheckResult)' == 'Downgrade' OR '$(TypeScriptVersionCheckResult)' == 'Upgrade'"
      Culture="$(PreferredUILang)"
      Name="TypeScriptVersionMismatchWarning"
      Arguments="$(TypeScriptToolsVersion);$(LastKnownTypeScriptVersion)">
      <Output TaskParameter="String" PropertyName="TypeScriptVersionMismatchWarning" />
    </FormatLocalizedString>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- Don't emit any warnings about TS version if TypeScriptCompileBlocked is set or if there is nothing to compile -->
      <TypeScriptShowVersionWarning Condition="'$(TypeScriptShowVersionWarning)' == '' AND '$(TypeScriptCompileBlocked)' != 'true' AND ('@(ConfigFiles)' != '' OR '@(TypeScriptCompile)' != '')">true</TypeScriptShowVersionWarning>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Warning Condition="'$(TypeScriptShowVersionWarning)' == 'true' AND '$(TypeScriptVersionCheckResult)' == 'NoneSpecified'" Text="$(TypeScriptNoVersionWarning)" />
    <Warning Condition="'$(TypeScriptShowVersionWarning)' == 'true' AND ('$(TypeScriptVersionCheckResult)' == 'Downgrade' OR '$(TypeScriptVersionCheckResult)' == 'Upgrade')" Text="$(TypeScriptVersionMismatchWarning)" />
    <Warning Condition="'$(TypeScriptBuildMode)' == 'true' AND ($(TypeScriptToolsVersion.StartsWith('2.')) OR $(TypeScriptToolsVersion.StartsWith('1.')))" Text="TypeScriptBuildMode requires TypeScriptToolsVersion 3.0 or higher" />
  </Target>
```

This my project file xml

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

Comment: Please open the project file and search for "FormatLocalizedString". If it exists, please share the XML node in your question. In fact, it would be even better if you can share your entire project file's XML.

Comment: I couldn't find  "FormatLocalizedString" in my project. I have share XML in the edits

Comment: Could you show your visual studio version and sdk version?

Comment: Visual studio -2022- 17.6.2   and  dot net sdk 7.0.3

Comment: It's really strange error and still failed to repo,it add typescript support with npm/nuget now,have you tried to convert the target node  to comment in  Microsoft.TypeScript.targets?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/compile-typescript-code-nuget?view=vs-2022

Comment: Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild i added this NuGet package and this resolved my issue

Comment: @winstondsouza you will continue to run into issues in the future. Adding one package fixes the current build, but unless you fix your installation as mentioned in my answer, you will have problems again.

Comment: @JuanR I could see only one path in my environment variable. I did a repair from visual studio installer it didn't fix.

Answer (score 3):

I just helped a colleague troubleshoot this issue and in their case it was because they didn't have version 4.3 of the TypeScript SDK installed on their machine (should be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\4.3`).  Installing the TypeScript SDK v4.3 from the Visual Studio Marketplace resolved the issue for them: [TypeScript 4.3 for Visual Studio - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.TypeScript-43).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by installing a package in my project :

first : open nuget package manager and choose the browser tab , then search the
'typescript' word in search box:

then you will see a package called 'Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild'.

after installing this package , you should rebuild the project , then the problem will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue that was supposed to be [Fixed In Visual Studio 2022 version 17.0.1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Installing-VS2022-breaks-dotnet-tool/1575432).

Long story short, the project is importing the Typescript targets and it can't find the tasks in your computer. This happens because the installation of VS 2022 adds a second path for the SDKs to the Windows `PATH` variable, which causes this behavior. You can see your `PATH` variable using the following at the command line:

```
echo %PATH%
```

You should see the dotnet path repeated in there somewhere with a slightly different location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\

[Reinstall the SDK you need](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks) for your machine to fix this and make sure the installation path matches the above.

Answer (score 0):

In the project properties screen, change the type script version to the latest version, or install the missing typescript version if you need a specific one, see the below image

[image]